# Only able to connect to a SQLServer Database using Integrated Security

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a database with a Process account, but I am only able to connect using IntegratedSecurity. If I try to set it manually the application throws an error due to not being able to login with the user.

I tried to run this code on different languages, but same issue happens.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            Console.WriteLine("Connect to SQL Server and demo Create, Read, Update and Delete operations.");
            // Build connection string
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = "datasource";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "warehouse";
            builder.UserID = "user";
            builder.Password = "pass#$word";
            //builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            // Connect to SQL
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to SQL Server ... ");
            Console.WriteLine(builder);
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString)) {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("All done. Press any key to finish...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to connect to the database without the need of the IntegratedSecurity.

Also, this is to a remote server, not local host. I am able to connect in SSMS using Windows Authentication, but if I try to set it to pass the credentials hard-coded, it throws an error message.

The error (from the comments)

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for
>   user 'user'. at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)

Comment: Are you able to connect through SSMS? Also share the exception you are getting in Visual Studio, that will give more details.

Comment: Hey Nitesh. Sure, this is the error:Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'user'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks anyway Guido!

Comment: Check in `Sql Server Configuration Manager` if the `TCP/IP` and the `Named Pipes` protocol is enabled.

Comment: An easy way to test is creating a text file, and rename it with extension `.UDL` Now just doubleclick on this empty .udl file and you will get a prompt for building and testing a connection string. Once you have this working, open it with notepad and you will find the connection string there

Comment: So I just tested this (thanks for the info, didn't knew about it). And the integrated security worked, but if I input my account (which has access) it doesn't work. Is this due to the TCP/IP or/and Named Pipes not being enabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'db123'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186685/sqlexception-0x80131904-login-failed-for-user-db123)

Comment: It sounds more like a problem with this users credentials. You should check these. Can you login with SSMS using these credentials ?

Comment: So I am using my Windows Credentials, so is there any difference between using the Integrated Security (which uses my Windows Credentials) and using hard-coded the Windows Credentials? I tried to login using the SSMS, but all options give me an error message

Comment: @NiteshSaxena, that isn't a solution to my problem. That one doesn't even have a solution.

Comment: If you set integrated security to false, and specify a username and password it tries to log in using a SQL Server account, not a Windows account. I don't think you can specify a Windows logon with credentials manually like that, instead you have to make your code run in the context of the desired user, and then use integrated security. The whole point of using a windows login for SQL is not to have to enter or store the credentials. Either make your code run as this other windows account, or switch to using a SQL account

Answer (score -1):

Just make

`builder.IntegratedSecurity = false;`

It will work.

Comment: By the way, IntegratedSecurity is set to false by default. You have to set it to true in the code, so this is redundant.